# GASの月トリガーに26日が2つあり、25日がありません

Tags: google-apps-script

GoogleAppsScriptの月トリガーに26日が2つあり、25日がありません。
昨日26日にメール送信するように設定したトリガーが動いてしまいました。

Googleに連絡しても、サポート外とのことで対応したいただけませんでした。
こちらで何かわかる方がいらっしゃれば教えていただけませんでしょうか。
[image: 月トリガー日にち選択画面]

Comment: 「GoogleAppsScriptの月トリガーに26日が2つあり、25日がありません。」というのは、あなたが書いたGoogleAppsScriptがそのようになっているからでしょう。それの修正方法が知りたいのなら、あなたが書いたGoogleAppsScriptのプログラムを質問に書かないとダメです。あなた以外の人は、あなたがどんなプログラムを書いたのか知らないのですから。

Comment: いま確認したところ、確かに26日の選択肢が2つありますね。Googleの不具合でしょうからどうしようもないと思います。ただ、最初の方の「26日」が実際は25日の指定になるように見えます。

Comment: Fumu 7様　説明不足で失礼しました。Googleの設定画面そのものなので、私のプログラム云々ではありません。

Comment: int32_t様　ご確認ありがとうございます。利用者から、以前の設定画面で「26日」に設定したものが「25日」に動いたと報告を受けています。どちらに連絡すればよろしいかご存知ありませんでしょうか？今月は既に27日になってしまっているため検証も難しい状況です。